# Standard vs wide shimano shoes

Tags: road-bike, shimano, shoes

Would my normal sized feet still fit snug on a wide shimano shoes? I’m looking to buy the RP3 but only the “wide” is available. I’m buying online so i can’t personally try it on. Appreciate all the help. Thanks.

Comment: I'd never buy shoes on line.  Go try them in a retail shop.   Is not worth all the freight costs to send stuff back when it doesn't quite fit.

Comment: In my experience Shimano is quite small and narrow, so the wide variant could fit nicely. I do agree with Criggie that trying them on is best.

Comment: Yes, they said it’s narrow and suggests going a size up. I’m size 10 US, 44 in eu, so it’s 45 eu if i size up. I was wondering if i don’t need to size up if i’m geting the wide size. Their shop is quite far so buying online is the better option for me.